# database design, create other table , or add category field?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table named `size` here, something like this:

```
size id | size name 
   1            S
   2            M
   3            L
   4            XL
```

But I am confused when I found that the size must have any category, I mean something like `cloth_size`, `pant_size`, `sheets_size`. That would be different. Row will be `6XL`, `5XL`, `4XL`. I think I should crate the table `sheets_size` like:

```
size id size name 
1            S
2            M
3            L
4            XL
5            XXL
```

or should I create the table `category` like:

```
category_id category_name
1              cloth
2              dress
3              pants
4              sheets
```

table `size`:

```
size id | size name   | category
1            S              1
2            M              1
3            L              1
4            XL             1  
5            XXL            4
```

Which one better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best and easiest method is to have a table with all categories, like you described:

```
category_id  |   category_name
    1        |      cloth
    2        |      dress
    3        |      pants
    4        |      sheets
```

and then have a table with all sizes (from S to 6XL)

```
   size id   |   size name 
      1      |       S
      2      |       M
     ...     |      ...
      10     |      6XL
```

These two tables will be in a many-to-many relationship since one category can have many sizes and one size can belong to many categories. This means that you will need a third table to hold the primary keys of each table.

```
   category_id   |   size_id
        1        |      1
        1        |      2
       ...       |     ...
```

This basically translates to category 1, has sizes 1 and 2, as in cloth has sizes S and M.

Comment: thanks for the answer mr alegen, but why it is better than my first table??

Comment: it depends on the normalization level you are aiming for; your solution is good for 3nf but does not meet the 4nf: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form

Comment: yes this is better, in this way you can put same size in different categories.